# Issues creating a Json object that does not remove trail zeros

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have successfully created a JSON object in snowflake with `object_construct_keep_null` The problem I am having is, the output removes any trailing zeros

```
 select "ID",
object_construct_keep_null('balcash',"cashBalance",'currency',"currency",'date',"createdAt") "Balance"
```

output is

```
{
  "balcash": 0.06,
  "date": "2022-04-06",
  "currency": "DKK"
}
```

Before creating the json object the value of balcash was 0.06000. I expect it to maintain the exact value. is there something I can do to ensure my values remain the same?
expected json object.

```
 {
      "balcash": 0.06000,
      "date": "2022-04-06",
      "currency": "DKK"
    }
```

Comment: There is another similar post - seems like issue in snowflake: "https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Solution-Precision-lost-while-loading-FLOAT-data-from-Oracle-to-Snowflake". Though I dont think solution mentioned exactly gives what is in source.

Comment: What decimal precision is being specified for balcash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to maintain decimal precision, you'll need specify the precision and cast it to string before you construct the object

```
object_construct_keep_null('balcash',"cashBalance"::decimal(10,5)::varchar,
                           'currency',"currency",
                           'date',"createdAt")
```